# How do I draw an svg polyline with 45 degree?

Tags: svg.js

I use [svgdotjs/svg.draw.js](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.draw.js) for drawing some shape.
 I have a situation where I want to draw a line with 45 and 90 degree, can I do it with this extension?

```js
const poly3 = new SVG('canvas').size('100%', '100%');
const line = poly3.polyline(null).fill('none').stroke({width: 2}).draw();
poly3.on('dblclick', event => {
     line.draw('start', event);
}

poly3.on('mousemove',event=>{
    const position=Object.assign({},event)
    console.log('ttttt')
    let x=event.x - this.startX;
    let y=event.y - this.startY;
    let r = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    let angle = (Math.atan2(y, x) / Math.PI * 180);
    angle = (angle) % 360 + 180;

    if (angle <= 22.5 || angle >= 337.5) {
        angle = 0;
    } else if (angle <= 67.5) {
        angle = 45;
    } else if (angle <= 112.5) {
        angle = 90;
    } else if (angle <= 157.5) {
        angle = 135
    } else if (angle <= 202.5) {
        angle = 180
    } else if (angle <= 247.5) {
        angle = 225
    } else if (angle <= 292.5) {
        angle = 270
    } else if (angle < 337.5) {
        angle = 315
    }
    angle -= 180;

    let cosx = r * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    let sinx = r * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);


})
```

How can I update line with new x and y?

Comment: I'm not able to get your example to run at all, so I have provided a alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [svgdotjs/svg.draw.js 2.0](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.draw.js) only works with [svg.js 2.7](https://svgjs.com/docs/2.7/) and **not** svg.js 3.0.

It seems that you are using svg.js 2, so the following should work with your setup.

One thing to note, is that when you call `line.draw('update', { clientX, clientY })` the `drawupdate` event handler will be called immediately. I solved it by using a boolean called `update`. I simply toggle the value between `mousemove` and `drawupdate` to avoid infinite recursion.

There is a bug in svg.draw.js@2.0.4 in how the offset is set when initialized and not updated. That means that if you scroll, then the offset is wrong and all of the positions will also be wrong. I'm working on a PR that will fix that and a couple of other things.

```js
'use strict'

const poly3 = SVG('canvas')
const line = poly3.polyline().fill('none').stroke({
    width: 2
})

let update = true
let snappedPoint

const startPoint = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}

poly3.on('dblclick', event => {
    const { clientX,  clientY } = snappedPoint || event
    startPoint.x = clientX
    startPoint.y = clientY

    line.draw('point', snappedPoint || event)
})

poly3.on('mousemove', () => {
    update = true
})

line.on('drawupdate', event => {
    if (update) {
        update = false
        snappedPoint = snapTo45(startPoint, event.detail.p)
        line.draw('update', snappedPoint)
    }
})

function snapTo45(startPoint, currentPoint) {
    // solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510911/205696
    const deltaX = currentPoint.x - startPoint.x,
        deltaY = currentPoint.y - startPoint.y,
        dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2))

    const angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX)
    const snappedAngle = Math.round(angle / Math.PI * 4) / 4 * Math.PI

    return {
        clientX: startPoint.x + dist * Math.cos(snappedAngle),
        clientY: startPoint.y + dist * Math.sin(snappedAngle)
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body, svg {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#canvas {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.7.1/svg.min.js" integrity="sha256-DSAVgUuz6YXM7pUOvn+Lc40Ek6cWvBgCBU1jsx72Dqg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/svg.draw.js@2.0.4/dist/svg.draw.min.js"></script>
```

To calculate the angle I used the solution provided at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510911/205696.
**EDIT** <strike>It is not perfect but it *mostly* works.</strike> Turns out that the solution is perfect but we need to update our `startPoint` with the snapped position on `dblclick` and not the real position from `event` or the calculation will be wrong.